# "Problem loading output layers" error when running algorithms on rasters in QGIS

Tags: qgis, raster, error, catchment

I am trying to delineate a catchment from SRTM 1arc second data in QGIS. For this, I first try to use the `Fill Sinks` algorithm and then the `Catchment Area` algorithm. Both of the operations gives a "Problem loading output layers" error, as follows:

```
Load grid: C:\Users\Douw\AppData\Local\Temp\processing\36e1cab1d1424b9fa4584d564393ad6d\demclip1.sgrd...
failed
Usage: saga_cmd ta_preprocessor 3 -DEM [-RESULT ] [-MINSLOPE ]
-DEM: DEM
Grid (input)
-RESULT: Filled DEM
Grid (output)
-MINSLOPE: Minimum Slope [Degree]
Floating point
Minimum: 0.000000
Default: 0.010000
Error: Grid file could not be opened.
Error: input file [C:\Users\Douw\AppData\Local\Temp\processing\36e1cab1d1424b9fa4584d564393ad6d\demclip1.sgrd]
Error: DEM
Error: executing tool [Fill Sinks (Planchon/Darboux, 2001)]
```

Comment: Is there a problem with the clip of your DEM file or file type? Did you try different file type but sgrd? What command did you execute?

Comment: I just tried to run the Fill Sinks algorithm from the Processing Toolbox.  I haven't tried a different file type yet.  I am able to run other processes on the clip, so it might be the file type.  Is there a way to convert the current clip to another type or should I download my data from a different source?

Comment: May check the manual eg. [Working with Raster Data](https://docs.qgis.org/2.8/en/docs/user_manual/working_with_raster/supported_data.html). To convert your current clip use `Raster menu - Conversion - Translate (Convert format)`... you may also save it under a different path...